# How to format my USB?

Tags: formatting

I have a Kingston USB drive and I want to format it but I can't do it. I've already tried the disk management and the diskpart but it won't work. Whenever I would format it, there will be a window that will appear saying that Windows can't format the disk. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried it from the CLI using administrative privileges? Try something like: format <drive letter>: /q /u /v

Comment: include a screenshot and try rufus.  I've found sandisk better than kingston anyway, fod speed and so maybe reliability, maybe it is faulty too. Try rufus anyway. and twhat jeroen said

Comment: Does it show 0 total space and 0 free space ? If so, you can throw it away. Otherwise it may be recoverable.

Comment: Kingston has a format utility program.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

try this in cmd.exe replace X for the disk number of your USB which is shown when you input `list disk`

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk X
clean
create part pri
select part 1
format fs=ntfs quick
exit
```